# IMAP client using OpenSSL library

Tags: openssl, imap

I am trying to write a simple SSL IMAP client. For that I am using OpenSSL library and C++ (g++ compiler). I found much information about IMAP and I can successfully communicate with IMAP server. But I noticed that when there is no data to receive, BIO_read() blocks forever. I also tried with SSL_read() in non-blocking(?) mode by looking [this](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~choua/school/cs165/openssl-examples-20020110/wclient2.c) example (I didn't use certificate verification) and get the same problem.

Simplified source code:

```
<...>
BIO *bio;
SSL *ssl;
SSL_CTX *ctx;

CRYPTO_malloc_init(); // Initialize malloc, free, etc for OpenSSL's use
SSL_library_init(); // Initialize OpenSSL's SSL libraries
SSL_load_error_strings(); // Load SSL error strings
ERR_load_BIO_strings(); // Load BIO error strings
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); // Load all available encryption algorithms

ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "imap.gmail.com:993");
BIO_do_connect(bio);

char tmp[10000];
cout << "Bytes received: " << BIO_read(bio, tmp, 1000) << endl; //Got 68 bytes - full anwer (server welcome string)
cout << "Bytes received: " << BIO_read(bio, tmp, 1000) << endl; //No more data to receive - I expecting 0 (zero), but it blocks forever.
cout << "Bytes received: " << BIO_read(bio, tmp, 1000) << endl;
```

[There is full source code](http://pastebin.com/fiL82GiR) (see line 49)

---

P. S.: Sorry for my poor English, I hope that everyone understood.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BIO_pending()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_ctrl.html) to figure out if you should perform another BIO_read or not.

Something like:

```
while (bytes_remaining = BIO_pending(bio))
cout << "Bytes received: " << BIO_read(bio, tmp, bytes_remaining) << endl;
```

Might work for you.